# Create Dynamic Parameterised Query URLS in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**Challenge:**

I have a URL which has various query parameters
[Example Link](https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=POSTCODE%5E4046321&minBedrooms=2&maxPrice=200000&radius=0.5&sortType=6&propertyTypes=detached%2Csemi-detached%2Cterraced&primaryDisplayPropertyType=houses&mustHave=&dontShow=&furnishTypes=&keywords=)

Parameters such as:

- minBedrooms=2
- maxPrice=200000

I want to be able to dynamically create the links based on criteria I supply in Google Sheets.

For example: if I decide I want to check `minBedrooms=4` instead then I can just change a cell in Google sheets and it updates/formulates a new link.

One way I have managed to change a single parameter at the moment is by:

1. `Split` the URL by "&"
2. Using `RegexReplace` to find the number in the parameter e.g. 2 (minBedrooms=)
3. `Match` the text to get the `Index` of the `Split`
4. Use `Index` to get the full text of the `minBedrooms=2`
5. `Substitute` the `minBedrooms=2` for `minBedrooms=4`

I have added a Google Sheet which shows an example of one way I have managed to achieve this so far but it's far from elegant:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZGt2vIOcgovSVG_j1ARffyfss-VQLnQrPPa_-2Iwyk4/edit?usp=sharing

I want to be able to have multiple parameters that I can change to create the new link

Comment: Would you consider using a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) for this?

Answer (score 1):

The middle step with the split parameters is unnecessary. Where you have dynamic URL use the formula:

```
="https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=POSTCODE%5E4046321&minBedrooms="&B2&"&maxPrice="&B3&"&radius=0.5&sortType=6&propertyTypes=detached%2Csemi-detached%2Cterraced&primaryDisplayPropertyType=houses&mustHave=&dontShow=&furnishTypes=&keywords="
```

You see how I replaced the values for minBedrooms and maxPrice in the URL? By replacing the number that was there with "&B2&" and "&B3&" your parameters are automatically put in the link, changeable at any time.

Edit:
If you want to add more parameters, just add slots for them up top and substitute them in in the correct spots. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the problem with that is the links could change as in everything before the first parameter `minBedrooms=2` so I would need to add the "&B2&" each time I have another URL no?

Comment: The idea would be to be able to paste any Rightmove URL and for Google sheets to know that the minBedroom parameter is dynamic, along with any other params that could change too

Comment: That or you could just set up fields for all parameters on Rightmove.